# Is it possible to express this console based USA Flag drawn concisely with Python?

Tags: python, console

Is it possible to improve the following code written with python 2.7?

First of all forgive me if I have drawn the USA flag incorrectly. This is my first time python programming. I tried my best.

By the way I drew 5 lines of stars with space and two extra space after the stars and 4 lines of stars with one less space.

Then I have drawn the rest of the stripes.

```
import sys

first_time = True
second_time = False
first_stars = 6
second_stars = 5
total_lines = 11
stars1_col = 6
stars2_col = 5
total_tokens_per_line = 37
first_total_lines = 24

i = 0
for i in range(total_lines):
    if(first_time or second_time):
        # if second_time is true print space at the beginning of every
        # second line else just empty space
        if(second_time):
            sys.stdout.write(" ")
        # else no space
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("")

        # if first_time is true print a star and a space
        if(first_time):
            j = 0
            for j in range(stars1_col):
                sys.stdout.write("* ")

            # first line is done reverse these two variables   
            second_time = True
            first_time = False
        # if not first_time print "* " and at the end of stars
        # write space
        else:
            m = 0
            for m in range(stars2_col):
                sys.stdout.write("* ")

            # write an extra space after every second line of stars
            sys.stdout.write(" ")

            # reverse these two variables again
            first_time = True
            second_time = False

        # write an extra space after every second line of stars
        sys.stdout.write(" ")

        # draw the underscore lines (the stripes besides stars)
        l = 0
        for l in range(first_total_lines):
            sys.stdout.write("_")

        # now flush out or write stripes and stars besides stripes
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # if there are 8 lines printed print a newline
        print("")

        # if stars and stripes lines are total of 8 make these variables
        # false
        if (i == 8):
            first_time = False
            second_time = False

    # then draw the last lines, flush it and print new line    
    if ((not first_time) and (not second_time)):
        k = 0
        for k in range(total_tokens_per_line):
            sys.stdout.write("_")

        sys.stdout.flush()  
        print("")
```

The output of this code is:

[image: USA Flag on Console]

Comment: If you want advice on working code, you should instead go to [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use list comprehension with string joins.

```
print('\n'.join([''.join(['* '[(i + l) & 1] for i in range(11)]) + '  ' + '_' * 24 for l in range(9)] + ['_' * 37] * 3))
```

This outputs:

```
* * * * * *  ________________________
 * * * * *   ________________________
* * * * * *  ________________________
 * * * * *   ________________________
* * * * * *  ________________________
 * * * * *   ________________________
* * * * * *  ________________________
 * * * * *   ________________________
* * * * * *  ________________________
_____________________________________
_____________________________________
_____________________________________
```